# Call json response data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have json response like this :

```
{
    "gasal": [
        {
           "prodi": "Teknik Industri",
           "jumlah": "3.5000"
        },
        {
           "prodi": "Teknik Informatika",
           "jumlah": "6.0000"
        }
    ],
    "genap": [
        {
            "prodi": "Teknik Informatika",
            "jumlah": "2.0000"
        }
    ],
    "prodi": [
       {
           "nama_prod": "Teknik Informatika"
       },
       {
           "nama_prod": "Teknik Industri"
       }
   ]}
```

i want to show the response to bar chart (i use chart js), but the problem is i dont know how to call the json response in javascript.

this is my javascript code :

```
    var url = "{{url('test')}}";
    var Prodi = new Array();
    var gasal = new Array();
    var genap = new Array();
    $.get(url, function(response){
        response.forEach(function(data){
            Gasal.push(data.genap.jumlah);
            Genap.push(data.gasal.jumlah);
            Prodi.push(data.prodi.nama_prod);
        });
    })
```

i think the problem is in this code

```
 Gasal.push(data.genap.jumlah);
 Genap.push(data.gasal.jumlah);
 Prodi.push(data.prodi.nama_prod);
```

what is the right code ?
thank you.

Comment: `Gasal.push(data.genap[0].jumlah);` should work since the object is nested in the array

Answer (score 0):

Gasal.push(data.genap[0]) would be the whole object
Gasal.push(data.genap[0].jumlah) would be the property of the object
Because you have created an array with an object inside and then you need to access the properties of the object.